# custom time zone

Tags: windows, timezone

Is thee some way of implementing a custom time zone in windows?

We have some PCs in Creston, British Columbia, Canada ([Time zone exception](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_CA-BC1.aspx?city=Creston)) which stays the same time all year. So essentially, Creston does not observe a time zone.  Can I implement this behavior in windowsÉ

Comment: If you mean that you don't want Windows to adjust the clock for daylight savings, that should be configurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a lengthy blog post about a similar problem we had: http://subjectivecoder.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/creating-custom-windows-timezones.html

The short version is that there is a spot in the registry which allows you to modify or create new time zones - but the registry format is fairly nasty.

Microsoft has a GUI tool called TZEdit which you can find here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914387 (scroll down to Method 2 and download TZEdit.exe).

If you want to see what's going on behind the scenes, I've published the source to the command line tool I built here: https://github.com/Rophuine/TimeZoneInfoGenerator (it's untested and quick-and-dirty but may help you understand what's going on, if you're interested).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from daylight savings time, this is normal MST (UTC-0700), right?

Windows used to have a checkbox called something like "Automatically adjust the clock for daylight savings time". Maybe you can hunt that down. Even if there is no checkbox, chances are that the registry setting still exists.

Answer (score 1):

The data is in: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Time zones.

You can probably add your own zone.

Each zone has its own key. And they contain a lot of data. Some zones have a subkey Dynamic DST.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer, but you might consider trying to get Creston recognized as an official time zone. As for how exactly to do that... contact Microsoft, I guess, and ask where they get their time zone info from. Probably the closest thing to an official time zone database in computer programming is [zoneinfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo) but I'm not sure if Microsoft uses it.

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: You should be very careful about creating your own time zone, even if you think your systems are isolated.

This could cause problems with exchanging information with other systems, both from conversion errors as well as exception handling.

If the time zone you want is legally recognized, you should consider bothering your vendor to properly add you to the time zone repository they use.